# How to Connect VM over VPN on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: networking, vpn, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created a VPN Connection with FortiGate and "Established" a connection in Google Cloud, but when I try to ping a VM that's on the Compute Engine the request times out.

The subnet creation mode for the VM is `Legacy VPC network` and was automatically generated when migration the VM with CloudEndure.

How can I access the VM on the VPN?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) might be the culprit. (Did you also check your [routes](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes) to ensure there's a route to the other side of the VPN tunnel?)